reset page and total page number in fancy footer with input files
I have a document that comes in two parts. I am compiling it using \input{} from multiple files. This the minimal working example in the file called main.tex:
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[C]{\color{gray}{My Document}}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{
\setlength{\fboxsep}{6pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5pt} % Thickness of the border
\fcolorbox{black}{lightgray!60}{\hspace{0.38\linewidth}
Page \thepage~of \pageref*{sec:endpage}
\hspace{0.38\linewidth}
}}
\begin{document}


\setcounter{page}{1}
\input{file1}
\input{file2}
\ref{sec:endpage}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\input{file3}
\ref{sec:endpage}

\end{document}


I know that the contents of file 1 and 2 together make up 12 pages, and content of file 3 makes up 14 pages. I want the fancy-footer to count Page 1 of 12, 2 of 12 ... 12 of 12. And once it reaches file 3, to reset as Page 1 of 14, Page 2 of 14...
Currently I am able to reset the current page number using \setcounter{page}{1}, but the total pages comes as a ??.
I have seen a previous similar question to this: Reset page numbering and total number of pages per section, but I am unable to work a solution even after trying that out.

You probably mean \label{sec:endpage} instead of \ref{sec:endpage}. Otherwise sec:endpage will not defined, which is what you observe.
However, you cannot redefine a label, so you would need two different ones, and then change the footer in file 3 to use the second one.
Another problem: You would have to insert a \newpage before resetting the page number to 1, otherwise the change will be done on the last page of file 2, and the number of pages of the first part will also be reset to 1 (the \label command will pick up te page number when the page is output to the PDF file, not when the command is given).
Here is an example, where I put \lipsum commands in the files.
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=15mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\newcommand{\numberofpages}{\pageref*{sec:endpage1}}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[C]{\color{gray}{My Document}}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{
\setlength{\fboxsep}{6pt}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5pt} % Thickness of the border
\fcolorbox{black}{lightgray!60}{\hspace{0.38\linewidth}
Page \thepage~of \numberofpages
\hspace{0.38\linewidth}
}}
\begin{document}


\setcounter{page}{1}
\input{file1}
\input{file2}
\label{sec:endpage1}
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\renewcommand{\numberofpages}{\pageref*{sec:endpage2}}
\input{file3}
\label{sec:endpage2}

\end{document}


